# How to use limitTo in typehaead Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typeahead

How can i limit the number the typeahead results to 5 or something in Angular 4 ?
I have attached the official plunker link here. I'm not able to use `|limitTo`

http://embed.plnkr.co/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3/

This is the template

```
<section class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="search-results style-3">
      <input type="text" [value]="query"
        ngxTypeahead
        [taUrl]="url"
        [taParams]="params"
        (taSelected)="handleResultSelected($event)"
      >
    </div>
  </section>
```

This is ts file

```
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'This is Angular TypeAhead v' + systemConfig.map['ngx-typeahead'].split('@')[1].split('/')[0];

  public url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search';
  public params = {
    hl: 'en',
    ds: 'yt',
    xhr: 't',
    client: 'youtube'
  };
  public query = '';

  handleResultSelected (result) {
    this.query = result;
  }

  generateWord() {
    return chance.word();
  }
}
```

Comment: @sajeetharan where was it asked before? can you send the duplicate question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Angular, there is no `limitTo` filter, its called [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe).

Use `| slice:0:3` instead of limitTo

```
<input type="text" ngxTypeahead [value]="query3" [taList]="staticList | slice:0:3" (taSelected)="handleStaticResultSelected($event)">
```

Updated plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/wqTHY2rHknXHF412BELQ?p=preview